# How to deal with ellipses (...) when using formals() to change the default arguments of an R function written by someone else

Tags: r, function, arguments

When there is an R function such that my usage consistently differs from the defaults, to keep my code concise and easier to maintain, I like to do something like the following at the beginning of my script (in this example I'm using `ll()` from the `R.oo` package):

```
> formals(ll.default)$private <- T;
```

This works great. However, now I want to create a default option that the function reads from its `...` argument (in this example, I want to add the argument `is.function=F` to the defaults, and `...` is the second formal argument). Does anybody have any idea how to do that? I tried the following...

```
> formals(ll.default)[[2]]$is.function <-F
Error in formals(ll.default)[[2]]$is.function <- F : 
  argument "*tmp*" is missing, with no default

> formals(ll.default)$`...`$is.function <-F
Error in formals(ll.default)$...$is.function <- F : 
  argument "*tmp*" is missing, with no default

> formals(ll.default)$`...`<-alist(is.function=F)
> ll()
Error in ll.default() : '...' used in an incorrect context
> formals(ll.default)$`...`<-pairlist(is.function=F)
> ll()
Error in ll.default() : '...' used in an incorrect context
```

I looked at the `Defaults` package, but the documentation says:

> Currently, it is NOT possible to pass values for . . . arguments, only
>   formally specified arguments in the original function definition

Does anybody know of a way to accomplish this, short of writing a wrapper because of just one argument?

Comment: Seems like you could just `functional::Curry` it?

Comment: Oh, so THAT's what `Curry()` is for? The Wikipedia on the concept of Currying was over my head and the package docs were a link to a discussion thread which I didn't follow till just now. The downside is that `Curry()` is interpreted code and amounts to generating a wrapper for the target function. On the other hand, I guess the `formals()` approach creates a copy of that function in your local environment, so either way it's ugly. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Curry` in the `functional` library:

```
library(functional)
> test <- function(private=FALSE,...) return(private)
> Curry(test,private=TRUE)
function (...) 
do.call(FUN, c(.orig, list(...)))
<environment: 0x4d0bed8>
> testP <- Curry(test,private=TRUE)
> testP()
[1] TRUE
> test()
[1] FALSE
> test2 <- function(...,private=FALSE) return(private)
> test2()
[1] FALSE
> test2P <- Curry(test2,private=TRUE)
> test2P()
[1] TRUE
```

However, this fails with your desired example function, `ll`, which leads me to believe something else is going on:

```
> llP <- Curry(ll, private=TRUE)
> ll()
  member data.class dimension objectSize
1    llP   function      NULL       1008
> llP()
Error in get("...", envir = envir) : 
  argument "..." is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Well, at least this will be handy for other, more normal dot-containing functions. I bit my lip and wrote a wrapper that calls `R.oo:::ll.default`    Oh.    Hey, that might be what's wrong. `ll()` is a generic function and `ll.default()` is where most of the action is, so that might be the correct target for `Curry()`.

Comment: @f1r3br4nd Still can't make it work with `ll.default`.  I think the problem is that Curry uses `...` and then `ll.default` tries various tricks on `...` and the two aren't playing nicely.

Comment: Off-topic to my original post, but an interesting way to totally jack `ll()`: create an object in your environment that is an unevaluated call and then make that call impossible to evaluate by removing one of the objects it references. `ll()` will stop with an error when it attempts to retrieve information on that object. So, in addition to adding `is.function=F`, I now added `is.call=F` to my wrapper.